# Can We Make ajax Modal popup responsive in asp.net? If Yes Can we Please Tell Me How?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I want Make Modal popup in asp.net website responsive..which contains a grid-view in it

Comment: I made gridview responsive using Footable but no luck with Modal Popup.

Comment: Would this get the job done: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/? Assuming that the content inside (gridview and all its children) doesn't have a fixed width.

Comment: Another alternative: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/